# Can anyone tell me why I'm getting a Type Mismatch error when i attempt to run this code?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Range("C4").Value <> "" & Range("D4").Value <> "" & Range("E4").Value <> "" & Range("F4").Value <> "" & Range("G4").Value <> "" & Range("H4").Value <> "" & Range("I4").Value <> "" Then

Set i = Sheets("Sheet2")

Set e = Sheets("Sheet3")

Dim d

Dim j

j = 3

Do Until IsEmpty(e.Range("C" & j))

If e.Range("C" & j, "F" & j) = i.Range("C4:F4") Then

If e.Range("G" & j) Is Nothing Then

e.Range("G" & j, "I" & j) = i.Range("G4:I4")

Else

End If

Else

i.Range("C4:I4").Copy

e.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

j = j + 1

Loop

Else

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: I believe it is on this line: If e.Range("C" & j, "F" & j) = i.Range("C4:F4") Then

Answer (score 0):

Your Type Missmatch is because you are comparing Ranges with more than one cell like this:

```
If e.Range("C" & j, "F" & j) = i.Range("C4:F4") Then
```

VBA does not know what to answer as it does not know what do you expect to see, when you compare 4 cells with 4 cells.

In order to make something meaningful, you should implement a function, that compares the ranges. Something like this to get you started:

```
Public Function CompareRanges(rngA As Range, rngB As Range) As Boolean

    If rngA.Count <> rngB.Count Then
        CompareRanges = False
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'loop through the cells of rngA and compare them with rngB
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to VBA, I'm not really sure what the code you have written means or does

Comment: Basically I have 4 cells with information in a row and I want to press a button that searches through the list of the same type of data on the next worksheet to see if the first two cells are already in the list and if so paste the second two cells onto that same row, but if not paste all 4 cells onto the bottom of the list.

Comment: @O.Renwick, find a tutorial that explains the VBA `if ... then` command. also find a tutorial about VBA functions

Comment: @O.Renwick, please add that last comment to your question